# Regex: Find duplicated phrases

Tags: regex

Sometimes, I sometimes find the whole phrase repeated in my text.

```
The reason the reason why they cleaned....
```

**\b(\w+)\s+\1\b** finds repeated words, but, not phrases.

Comment: Add `(?:\s+\w+)*` after `\w+` and use a case insensitive modifier.  See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/4UIrxu/1).

Comment: `\w+` is for word. You need to write the correct regex to match the sentences you're interested in

Comment: Repeated where ? Adjacent or discontinuous ? What about `The reason, the reason` ? There is more to this than a homogenous premise. Might as well make it something _real world_..

Comment: The discontinues could be more complex to get it right. The continues one could be enough for me, for now.

Comment: `discontinues could be more complex to get it right.` Maybe not, if they are adjacent, all you'd need to do is put in a clause for punctuation `<here>\1\b` but punctuation can change the meaning of language significantly. It's good to realize you are not finding duplicate _phrases_ at all, since regex can't parse language.. that's impossible ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
\b(\w+(?:\s*\w*))\s+\1\b
```

check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/4UIrxu/2)

Comment: nice copy of @WiktorStribiżew's answer in the comments section above!

Comment: his regex fails keyword matches like the case "the the check"